# Is it possible to get an ordered result set from Contact and Lead using one query

Tags: apex, soql

Here is a problem I and team are trying to solve –

1. Lookup a list of contacts and leads associated with a given company
2. Order by specific field(s) eg -  Name, Title, Email  (The ordering should happen on the combined result set from contact and lead)
3. Send the top X records from the ordered result set from mid-tier APEX to the Javascript client.

Approach we are considering –

Since Contacts and Leads are in two distinct SF objects and since Salesforce lacks ( to our knowledge ) the concept of a database view,
the only way we see to consolidate query results from these two objects is to

1. Query Contact and Lead separately using sort on the sort field (passed in by the UI)
2. Build a tabular in-memory data structure and populate it with the top X records of the two query results.
3. In addition, sort the in-memory table on the sort field.
4. Return the top X records from the above sorted record set.

We would appreciate any suggestions on the following  –
1. Is there a better approach we can take where we can just leverage the ORDER BY provided by SOQL or SOSL? 
2. If we have to build the in-memory data structure and sort a 2nd time, what is the best way to do this?
3. Is it possible to build a tabular data structure in APEX (similar to Guava library’s ‘Table’)

Thank you for your time